# detect whether a CSS animation is running with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Here is my code for an animation:

```
.animated{transition:all ease 5s;position:absolute;right:200px}
window.setInterval(function(){
   $('.animated').css("right",parseInt($('.animated').css('right'))+5)
},2000);
$('.animated').click(function(e){
   if (e == //css animation executing){
       console.log('animation on the go')
   })
   else if (e == //css animation completed){
       console.log('animation completed')
   }
})
```

Can I use JavaScript to detect whether a CSS animation is running?

Comment: You can get an Javascript event, when CSS animation ends - `AnimationEnd`, like `.on('AnimationEnd')` you can also add browser prefixes to it. Check this article on : [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-animation-javascript-event-handlers/) it may help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could save your old `right` position of your `element`.
Insert it before all of your code maybe.

```js
// Old Right Position
// Keep in top

var oldRightPos = document.querySelector('.animated').style.right;

// Your animation...
window.setInterval(function(){
   $('.animated').css("right",parseInt($('.animated').css('right'))+15)
},2000);

// Part where you detect animation

$('.animated').click(() => {

if (oldRightPos <= document.querySelector('.animated').style.right) {

alert('CSS ANIMATION RUNNING!!!');

}else{

alert('still no luck:(');

}});
```

```css
.animated{transition:all ease 5s;position:absolute;right:200px
```

```html
<div class='animated'>HELLO</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe that'll do. :)